# How do I let the window created by GLUT non-resizable?

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I'm using Ubuntu/Mesa/FreeGlut/C.

Answer (score 1):

GLUT can't do that, sorry. Solution: Don't use GLUT. Take a look at SDL.

Answer (score 0):

try making a function on the windows resizing to set itself at it's original shape

```
void reshape(int x,int y) {
glutReshapeWindow(500, 500);//edit it with the size of your window
```

}

```
int main(){
//the stuff of your window
    glutDisplayFunc(windowCreationFunc);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutMainlLoop();
}
```

this will not prevent the user from trying to edit the size of the window,but the window will reshape itself automatically

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).